# connect postgres using sequelize my error is connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I can't connect the postgres using sequelize and node.js, error below

`

```
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Client._connectionCallback (/root/node1/teste/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:130:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/root/node1/teste/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorEvent (/root/node1/teste/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/root/node1/teste/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  },
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  }
}
```

`
I create 3 files in js to connect

db. js

`

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres', 'postgres', '12345', { 
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

`

produto.js
`

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const database = require('./db');

const Produto = database.define('produto', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    nome: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    preco: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE
    },
    descricao: Sequelize.STRING
})

module.exports = Produto;
```

`

index.js

`

```
'''''
`(async () => {
    const database = require('./db');
    const Produto = require('./produto');

    try {
        const resultado = await database.sync();
        console.log(resultado);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();`
'''
```

`

It's all my files in that project

This sync function will check if your model is matching your database. Missing tables it creates for you when needed.

Comment: The database is not accepting connections on the address (127.0.0.1) and port (5432). It is either not running, not running on the same machine as Node.js, not listening on the loopback interface or using another port. Can you connect from this machine with other tools, such as psql?

Comment: Have you tried using psql to connect to the database? Changing sequelize's config to mssql should not fix the issue here